# Generic credentials in Credential Manager

Tags: windows-10, credentials

I am a bit confused, can someone explain a bit more what generic credentials are in Credential manager? Are they security tokens as well as basic type credentials?

I can see some basic entries there as well as some others, but I'm not sure what they are (all of them are Office 365 related under Generic Credentials).

Answer (score 0):

> Generic credentials are defined and authenticated by applications that manage authorization and security directly instead of delegating these tasks to the operating system. For example, an application can require users to enter a user name and password provided by the application or to produce a certificate to access a website.
>
> Applications use Credentials Management functions to prompt users for application-defined, generic, credential information, such as user name, certificate, smart card, or password. The information entered by the user is returned to the application for authentication.
>
> Credentials Management provides customizable cache management and long-term storage for generic credentials. Generic credentials can be read and written by user processes.

Taken from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/kinds-of-credentials

Comment: I have read the specified article as well but it does not drop a hint if tokens are kept under generic credentials, thus I am a bit confused.